# read multiple gzip files from folder and unzip error in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I have created a workflow for reading all gzip files from a folder. Once done, i want to unzip those. I am getting error as follows

```
Starting job MyFirst at 08:55 22/03/2017.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3675
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tFileUnarchive_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at local_project.myfirst_0_1.MyFirst.tFileUnarchive_1Process(MyFirst.java:535)
at local_project.myfirst_0_1.MyFirst.tFileList_1Process(MyFirst.java:451)
at local_project.myfirst_0_1.MyFirst.runJobInTOS(MyFirst.java:933)
at local_project.myfirst_0_1.MyFirst.main(MyFirst.java:790)
[statistics] disconnected
Job MyFirst ended at 08:55 22/03/2017. [exit code=1]
```

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use a "flow -> Iterate" link insteed of "OnSubjectOk"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me. What is the difference between OnSubjectOk and iterate? I am unaware of that. Care to educate me?

Comment: To make it simple, "iterate" link will iterate on each file found by tFileList and execute tFileUnarchive. OnSubjobOk will execute tFileUnarchive only after tFileList finish (that's why you get a NullPointerException the first time). Best regards

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is helpful